# Get Storage not working in iOS flutter but working in android

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, storage

How can I get getStorage to work on flutter iOS the same code worked on android
without issues, Here is the error am currently seeing

```
#0      GetStorage._init (package:get_storage/src/storage_impl.dart:47:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      new GetStorage._internal.<anonymous closure> (package:get_storage/src/storage_impl.dart:28:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Operation timed out
#0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:88:7)
```

Here is the code on my page

```
main() async {
  await GetStorage.init();
  runApp(const SignIn());
}

class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignIn({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SignIn> createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
final box = GetStorage();
String token = '';

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSaved();
  }
}

getSaved(){
      setState(() {
        token = box.read('token');
      });
  }
```

Comment: please paste your code here to see

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you init the `get_storage` package in your `void main(){ }` like below:

```
void main() async {
  await GetStorage.init();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Here is the full example of [get_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage) :

[image]

**Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';

void main() async {
  await GetStorage.init();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter App',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String name = '';
  String result = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Get Storage Demo'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            // display result
            Text(
              result,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),

            TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter your name',
              ),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() => name = value);
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                GetStorage().write('name', name);
                // toast
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  SnackBar(content: Text('Saved: $name')),
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Save'),
            ),

            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  result = GetStorage().read('name');
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Display'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
#0      GetStorage._init (package:get_storage/src/storage_impl.dart:47:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      new GetStorage._internal.<anonymous closure> (package:get_storage/src/storage_impl.dart:28:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      main (package:d_aggregate/main.dart:13:3)
<asynchronous suspension>`

Comment: Share your full code

Comment: this is the full error now after adding `await GetStorage.init();` to the main.dart file

Comment: make async your void main function `void main() async {}`

Comment: still same the error shows up as soon as the app launches